# android/java/src/pcf: No such file or directory

Tags: android, c++, c, eclipse, debugging

I have tried to debug native c on Android,

but get the following error:

`There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin --target=arm-linux-android".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Warning: /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace/Client/src/android/java/src/pcf: No such file or directory.
Remote debugging from host 225.89.3.0
warning: while parsing target library list (at line 2): No segment defined for ..`

> Warning: /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace/Client/src/src/pcf: No such file or
>   directory. Reading symbols from
>   /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace/Client/src/android/java/obj/local/armeabi/app_process...done.
>
> WARNING: no debugging symbols found in
>   /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace/Client/src/android/java/obj/local/armeabi/app_process.
>   Either the binary was compiled without debugging information or the
>   debugging information was removed (e.g., with strip or strip -g).
>   Debugger capabilities will be very limited.

how can I fix this?

Comment: How exactly did you try to "debug native c on Android"?  What tool did you use / commands did you type?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should try to re-compile your code using "gcc - g" or its variants, then debug it one more time.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually getting any errors (or at least, you haven't posted them). What you've shared are all warnings. This means you can do whatever you want, just be aware that thing might not run smoothly.

The first half of the first message is simply a no-warranty notification. This is normal for gdb.

Following that is a missing file warning. I'm not sure what the file is or what it does. Check manually to see if it is there, and if not, you may have to re-install something.  In the case that it is, check that gdb has sufficient privileges to access the file. (Remember this is just a warning message, so fixing it is not critical.)

The last warning is about the lack of debugging symbols. Debugging symbols are used to assist with debugging only, primarily to determine what binary instructions correspond to what sections of the source code. In gcc (and g++) these can be included by using the -g flag when compiling. Most IDEs will have a setting for this somewhere.